# NodeJS send HTTP code status to front-end

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am reading expressjs documentation and i sow that the `response` to the user can be sent like this:

```css
res.status(404).send('Sorry, we cannot find that!') //or
res.status(201).send('posted')
```

I want to know if according to best practices, is ok to send the s`http status code` like this:

```js
res.send({
  data: {
    user: "John
  },
  statusCode: 201,
  message: "POsted success"
})
```

It is ok the last structure or it exist another way to send data about the status?

PS: I am new to node js

Answer (score 2):

The `send` method doesn't use a `statusCode` property on the body parameter to determine what the status code should be.

Not only is it not best practise, it simply doesn't work.

Comment: also i am using nestJS (https://docs.nestjs.com/controllers), do you know how there to send `statusCode` together with  ` data: {
    user: "John
  },
  message: "POsted success"`...  ?

Comment: could you help with this please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66303961/use-spread-operator-to-combine-multiple-arrays-fetching-data-in-react-js